# Entity Framework não edita FK

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou com algumas dificuldades em um projeto grande, e tentei fazer uma réplica bem simples para postar aqui de forma que alguém possa me ajudar. Uma das dificuldades que estou tendo e de como editar os campos com chave  estrangeira (FK). Tenho três entidades: Veiculo, Marca e Modelo. Como eu não sei como funciona as regras de chave estrangeira, eu não sei como fazer para alterar esses dados corretamente.

Os dados da entidade Veículo eu consigo editar normalmente, mas se eu tentar mudar a Marca ou Modelo que foi cadastrado eu não consigo, o Entity simplesmente não edita os dois campos que fazem relacionamentos com Marca e Modelo. Pesquisei aqui no forum posts de pessoas que tiveram o mesmo problema, mas a solução dada aos problemas não se aplicam ao meu.

No exemplo, estou tentando mudar a Marca=3 e Modelo=6 do veículo de Id=3, mas o Eentity Framework não faz atualiza a Marca e o Modelo:

Como poderia resolver o problema para que funcione?

**Modelo**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Principal**

```
  class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Veiculo veiculo = new Veiculo()
            {
                VeiculoId = 3,
                Nome = "Carro",
                Marca = new MarcaApplication().ListId(2),
                Modelo = new ModeloApplication().ListId(6)
            };

            VeiculoApplication apVeiculo = new VeiculoApplication();
            apVeiculo.EditTB(veiculo);
        }
    }
```

**Camada Domain**

```
public class Veiculo
{
    public int VeiculoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Modelo Modelo { get; set; }
    public Marca Marca { get; set; }
}

public class Modelo
{
    public int ModeloId { get; set; }
    public string ModeloDescricao { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Veiculo> Veiculos { get; set; }
}

public class Marca
{
    public int MarcaId { get; set; }
    public string MarcaDescricao { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Veiculo> Veiculos { get; set; }
}
```

**Camada Application**

```
public class VeiculoApplication
{
    public DBContext db { get; set; }

    public VeiculoApplication()
    {
        db = new DBContext();
    }

    public void AddTB(Veiculo tb)
    {
        db.Veiculos.Add(tb);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void EditTB(Veiculo tb)
    {
        db.Entry(tb).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    public IEnumerable<Veiculo> ListAll()
    {
        return db.Veiculos.ToList();
    }
}

public class ModeloApplication
{
    public DBContext db { get; set; }

    public ModeloApplication()
    {
        db = new DBContext();
    }

    public Modelo ListId(int id)
    {
        return db.Modelos.Where(m => m.ModeloId == id).First();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Modelo> ListAll()
    {
        return db.Modelos.ToList();
    }
}

public class MarcaApplication
{
    public DBContext db { get; set; }

    public MarcaApplication()
    {
        db = new DBContext();
    }

    public void AddTB(Marca tb)
    {
        db.Marcas.Add(tb);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    public Marca ListId(int id)
    {
        return db.Marcas.Where(m => m.MarcaId == id).First();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Marca> ListAll()
    {
        return db.Marcas.ToList();
    }
}
```

**Classe Veículo Alterada**

```
public class Veiculo
{
    public int VeiculoId { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }        
    public int ModeloId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ModeloId")]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public Modelo Modelo { get; set; }

    public int MarcaId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MarcaId")]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public Marca Marca { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Com o Entity Framework é perfeitamente possível trabalhar em camadas, a forma como o "Cigano" está orientando a fazer é uma forma primitiva de trabalhar que contraria os padrões MVC. Não vi a aplicação de camadas no exemplo, sugiro que leia alguns artigos referente ao assunto no TI Selvagem e no Macoratti. http://www.tiselvagem.com.br/
http://www.macoratti.net/cshp_3c1.htm
http://www.macoratti.net/14/05/aspn_3cam.htm

Comment: Sim, eu vi alguns assuntos relacionados nos exemplos que postou e ajudou bastante. O exemplo do TI Selvagem é muito semelhante ao meu. Obrigada!

Comment: Você verificou as restrições do banco?

Comment: Sim Ivan, eu fiz essa verificação, o banco é gerado via código. Eu procurei em outros fóruns onde tinham pessoas com o mesmo problema, mas as soluções eram diversas, mas todos os exemplos que eu encontrava eram desenvolvidos em camadas de diferentes tipos. O William me passou um artigo que segue o mesmo modelo de camadas que o meu e estou tentando acompanhar o modelo. Você já teve problema semelhante?

Answer (score 7):

Não vai funcionar porque você está fazendo mal uso do Entity Framework.

Nesta sentença:

```
Veiculo veiculo = new Veiculo()
{
    VeiculoId = 3,
    Nome = "Carro",
    Marca = new MarcaApplication().ListId(2),
    Modelo = new ModeloApplication().ListId(6)
};
```

Você está trazendo duas classes de dois contextos diferentes, e usando um terceiro contexto para disparar a atualização:

```
public void EditTB(Veiculo tb)
{
    db.Entry(tb).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

A arquitetura do exemplo está **totalmente incorreta**. Não sei quem sugeriu isto pra você, mas sistemas feitos em Entity Framework não devem ser encapsulados em "aplicações", justamente porque o contexto tem que observar todas as três entidades, veículo, modelo e marca, envolvidas na atualização.

Ao separar, você cria três contextos que não se comunicam entre si, e que possivelmente devem disparar algum erro quando você verifica o `EntityState` do objeto dentro do contexto.

Assim sendo, a maneira correta de se trabalhar é da seguinte forma:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (DBContext db = new DBContext()) 
        {
            Veiculo veiculo = new Veiculo()
            {
                VeiculoId = 3,
                Nome = "Carro",
                Marca = db.Marcas.FirstOrDefault(m => m.MarcaId == 2),
                Modelo = db.Modelos.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ModeloId == 6)
            };

            db.Entry(veiculo).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu vi este modelo em artigos e alguns semelhantes a vídeos do Academy Live, nunca deu esse problema, inclusive eu cheguei a postar projetos aqui usando este padrão, isolando o contexto das demais classes passando só a classe modelo. Consegui resolver o problema determinando as chaves estrangeiras, porém, ao incluir a Marca, estou tendo outro erro. A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property value(s) of 'Marca.MarcaId' on one end of a relationship do not match the property value(s) of 'Veiculo.MarcaId' on the other end. Vou editar a minha pergunta com as modificações.

Comment: Não sei de que artigos você fala, mas se houver algum desses aqui, estão todos errados. Sobre este erro, ele quer dizer que você está usando uma chave estrangeira que não existe na tabela original, no caso, `Marca`.